# Where should my page be located in a Rails API project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

I'm building a Rails API only app, for a game I have had made with pure html/js. For better structure where should be the page located within the large Rails project (will add users and etc). Public? App? Should I create a folder at root level?

Comment: the rule of thumb is to store api controllers and views in `/api`. So you can store views in `app/views/api/[name_of_controller]/[name_of_view].*`

Comment: If it is an API-only Rails app then I would put the JavaScript client code into a separated repository and would deploy the client to another location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in many ways, If you wanna only provide an APIs.

Rails only API: [Rails API only](https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/how-to-make-rails-5-api-only)

Since only api may be interested in JWT authentication: [JWT Sample](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-ruby-on-rails/token-based-authentication-with-ruby-on-rails-5-api)

**Routes** - Sample !

```
namespace :api do
    namespace :v1, defaults: { format: :json } do
        resources :orders, only: [:index, :show,:create] do
            member do
                post 'cancel'
                post 'status'
                post 'confirmation'
            end
        end

        # Users
        resources :users, only: [] do
            collection do
                post 'confirm'
                post 'sign_in'
                post 'sign_up'
                post 'email_update'
                put  'update'
            end
        end
    end
end

#output
...
GET  /api/v1/orders(.:format)  api/v1/orders#index {:format=>:json}
POST /api/v1/orders(.:format)                  api/v1/orders#create {:format=>:json}
 GET  /api/v1/orders/:id(.:format)              api/v1/orders#show {:format=>:json}
 POST /api/v1/users/confirm(.:format)           api/v1/users#confirm {:format=>:json}
 POST /api/v1/users/sign_in(.:format)           api/v1/users#sign_in {:format=>:json}
```

**Controlers:** - sample!

```
#application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
end

#api/v1/app_controller.rb
module Api
    class V1::AppController < ApplicationController
       ...    
    end
end

#api/v1/users_controller.rb
module Api
    class V1::UsersController < V1::AppController
      ...
    end
end
```